# How to convert from text to PDF using conversion API in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

i'm working on a task that i want to convert text file into PDF one using conversion API that is in GAE , i tried as: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview

This is the code that i used:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files
import cgi, cgitb ; cgitb.enable()
import StringIO
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import mimetypes
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from mimetypes import guess_type
from google.appengine.api import conversion




def mime_type(filename):
    return guess_type(filename)[0]
class get(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
        file_upload = form['file']  
        name=file_upload.filename  

        m=mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]

        data=file_upload.file.read()
        buf = StringIO.StringIO()
        asset = conversion.Asset("text/plain", data, file_upload.filename)
        conversion_obj = conversion.ConversionRequest(asset, "application/pdf")
        result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
        if result.assets:
             for asset in result.assets:
                buf.write(asset.data)

        else:
             print "ERROR" 


        u_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type="application/pdf",_blobinfo_uploaded_filename="test.pdf")
        data=buf.getvalue()
        with files.open(u_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
        files.finalize(u_file)
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(u_file)
        blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)
        name2 =  blob_info.filename   
        self.response.out.write("""<html><br><body style="background-color:#CC9999"><b><font size="5" face="Batang" ><center> <li ><a href="download.py?blob_key=%s" style="color:black">%s

               </center></font><hr></body></html>            
                """ % (str(blob_key),str(name2)))




def main():

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [(r'/get.py', get)], debug=True)

    run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

download.py:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from mimetypes import guess_type

def mime_type(filename):
    return guess_type(filename)[0]
class Thumbnailer(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = self.request.get("blob_key")
        if blob_key:
            blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)


            if blob_info:
                save_as1 =  blob_info.filename
                type2=mime_type(blob_info.filename)
                self.send_blob(blob_info,content_type=type2,save_as=save_as1)

                return


def main():


    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            (r'/download.*', Thumbnailer),
        ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:i edited the code, and when i try to `print buf.getvalue()`,i get :failed to load pdf document.
But when i try to open this PDF,i can't open it and the adobe reader gives error immediately that it can't open the file. Sorry i'm still beginner,any help please? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working code sample(it's for Python2.7 runtime though). Good luck!

```
import os
import StringIO

from google.appengine.api import conversion
from google.appengine.api import files
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')

jinja2_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        tmpl = jinja2_env.get_template('index.jinja2')
        self.response.out.write(tmpl.render())


class PostHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.get('file')
        asset = conversion.Asset('text/plain', data, 'test.txt')
        conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, 'application/pdf')
        result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
        buf = StringIO.StringIO()
        if result.assets:
            for asset in result.assets:
                buf.write(asset.data)
        else:
            raise Exception('Conversion failed.')
        u_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/pdf',
                                        _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test.pdf')
        with files.open(u_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(buf.getvalue())
        files.finalize(u_file)
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(u_file)
        blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/post_file', PostHandler),
],
debug=True)
```

Comment: Takashi Matsuo:i got that **No module named jinja2 **??

Comment: :thank alot for you help,the errer was i wrote ** conversion_obj = conversion.ConversionRequest(asset, "application/pdf") ** instead of conversion.Conversion, i tried without request locally and that gave error so i wrote it with request but when i deploy it(check it online not locally)i didn't get that error,i didn't kow why?however the problem is solved thank for youu help.

Comment: Great to hear that. Sorry I was not able to point it out earlier. Anyway, good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: :No problem,the problem is solved eventually,thak you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your 'data' (retrieved by `data=file_upload.file.read()`) is correct?

Maybe you can stop using cgi module, and just use a request object that webapp creates for you like:

```
data = self.request.get('file')
```

BTW, please don't use private attributes like `asset._data`, use `asset.data` instead. Additionally, what the StringIO is for? Have you considered just writing `asset.data` directly to the opened file?

*Update: I think I find the cause.*

Just after the conversion, please do as follows:

```
if result.assets:
    for asset in result.assets
    buf.write(asset.data)
```

Comment: i checked the data that returned from **file_upload.file.read()** and it's correct, also there is no attribute in asset as public data just private one,i used StringIO to store the result then store this buffer into blobstore in GAE.

Comment: I updated my answer. In your original code, you write the original text data into the buffer. Please use data from result.assets.

Comment: What kind of problem? Can you try to explain your problem? For example, how do you download your blob file? It's not clear from your original post.

Comment: Where is your download handler(download.py?)?

Comment: Takashi Matsuo: download.py handler works correctly,i tested it in another application,here when i try to print **buf.getvalue()** on the screen,the o/p is failed to load pdf document?

Comment: Please don't use print for debugging. It's almost impossible you just say it works fine. Sorry, but I'll leave this thread unless you provide entire code.

Comment: :Ok i will add downlod.py,no problem at me.

Comment: I'll create a working code sample, so can you refer to it and try it by yourself?

Comment: :yes of course no problem ,but i get that **No module named jinja2 ** although i worked on python2.7?also what is this jinja2?